# Getting value of row that corresponds to distinct? (proc sql)

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have a dataset unique across 5 variables. The 5th is an identifier variable. Finally, I have a 6th variable, which is dependent on the identifier variable.

The identifier variable can appear in multiple places. The dependent variable will never change for a given value of the identifier variable.

I have code such as the following:

```
proc sql;
select
...
, count(distinct identifier) as n_ids
from
group by
```

Which selects the number of unique identifiers per group of 4 independent variables. I'm hoping to add on to this the sum of the 6th variable, which would be something like the following:

```
sum(case when distinct identifier then dependent_var else 0 end)
```

Which obviously does not work (and for good reason). Any clean way of finding this sum within the sql step?

Comment: it would be helpful if you added a small data sample.  I am not sure I fully understand what the data looks like and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to summarize the dataset first by the identifier:

```
proc sql;
select biggerstuff, identifier, max(depvar) 
from yourdataset
group by biggerstuff,identifier;
quit;
```

Then insert that in your larger query in the place of the 'from' statement (select blah, count(identifier), sum(depvar)).  Once you've pre-summarized it in the inner query you know that you only get 1 row per identifier so distinct isn't needed any longer.

Comment: Works. I was hoping there was an easy way to do it all within a single select, but that'll suffice